# ionic1 https service not working in ios device

Tags: angularjs, iphone, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I am in new in hybrid mobile field, now I working ionic1 and angularjs1, so now my service call used from angularjs $http service in controller. so my https urls are working in android devices. but not working in ios devices.In android http response on success function works, but in ios devices error function returns.

```
 $scope.doLogin = function(mobile) { 

          alert(mobile);
          $rootScope.user_devid; 

          var datas = { serviceinput: '{"Username":'+mobile+',"DeviceId":'+$rootScope.user_devid+',"PushnotificationId":"22","DeviceType":"1"}' };        
          $.ajax({
  url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx/pgr/external/mobileservice?serviceId=getLogin",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  headers: {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          },
        data: datas,
  success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    //$("#container").html(data);
    alert("Local success callback.");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
    alert("Local error callback.");
    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    },
  complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
    alert("Local completion callback.");
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
  }
})
}
```

Above i my code I am using jquery ajax. Now where the problem occured i don't. in ios devices can add any config settings.

```
    <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
</platform>
```

this is my config.xml file on platform ios.

Comment: what error does it return? Also do you have CORS correctly setup in server side?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this header

```
       headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }

       //replace application/x-www-form-urlencoded with undefined
```